# Finding the highest sum of consecutive non-zero numbers by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have a long list of results from serial observations by groups. The dataset looks like here:

```
df <- data.frame (ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                  EV = c(0,0,3,2,3,0,1,1,1,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,4,5,1,2,0,2,2,2,2))
```

ID #1 showed two consecutive series of non-zero numbers, 3-2-3 and 1-1. The sum of 3-2-3 is higher than 1-1, I want 8. ID #2 had 1-2 and 1, therefore the correct result is 3. ID #3 has 4-5-1-2 and 2-2-2-2, and so the desired result is 12.

I want to have a dataframe as output like here;

```
  ID RE
1  1  8
2  2  3
3  3 12
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PLease be more precise about what you'd define as a consecutive number. I think what you really mean are sequences without zero.

Comment: @deschen That's correct. I corrected the text accordingly. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a `data.table` approach.

```
library( data.table )
#make it a data.table
setDT(df)
#make groups based on group == 0 and get their sums
ans <- df[, .(sum = sum(EV)), by = .(ID, rleid( ID, EV == 0 ) ) ]
#get the maximum sum for each ID, and drop the rleid column created in the previous row
ans[ ans[, .I[sum == max(sum)], by=.(ID)]$V1][, rleid := NULL][]
#    ID sum
# 1:  1   8
# 2:  2   3
# 3:  3  12
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. I think I need to study data.table methods. Thanks again.